# Unable to download Glassfish tools for Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, oracle, download, glassfish, eclipse-kepler

I'm using STS based on Kepler 4.3.2. I am not able to download support for Glassfish from the Oracle site. Whenever I try to download via Eclipse Marketplace, I get this error message:

"No repository found at http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/kepler."

Could someone please enlighten me what the problem is with the site?

Answer (score 0):

Installation (using the Install button, dragged to running Eclipse workspace) from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-kepler works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the p2 repo is not available on `download.oracle.com` (it could be a glitch), you can always download the latest p2 repo and use it offline.

See the last "[Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (12.1.3.1)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)" (or a [previous release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-archive-1716547.html)), and download a repo like:

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.1/luna/oepe-12.1.3.1-luna-repository.zip
```

Or, for Kepler, an older one:

```
 http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.2.3/kepler/oepe-12.1.2.3-kepler-repository.zip
```

(you must do it from the web page, after accepting the license)